# Failed to read or create install properties file after 10% installing

Tags: android

The below error is seen in command prompt when executing the command

sdkmanager "platform-tools" "platforms;android-29"

## Error :

Accept? (y/N): y
Warning: Failed to read or create install properties file.
[===                                    ] 10% Installing Android SDK Platform 29

Answer (score 0):

for the above error the path can be like - `C:\Program Files\cmdline-tools\tools\bin` *(This is the path in which I have placed the sdk. Please use the path till bin in the location you have placed the sdk)*

From Windows search for command prompt and select run as administrator and give the below command based on your mobile android version

```
sdkmanager "platform-tools" "platforms;android-29"
```

Now it will be like - after solving the above issue

---

```
Accept? (y/N): y
[=======================================] 100% Unzipping... platform-tools/sqlit
```

you can try like I did above and give a tick if it worked for you. this  solution worked for me 100%.